# getting number of collisions, double hashing

Tags: python

Use double hashing to get from table 1 to table 2 number of collisions is recorded

```
number = 11
first_prime = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
second_prime = [2, 3, 5, 7]

results = [[0]*len(first_prime) for i in range(len(second_prime))]

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
        for row in results]))
```

have:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0   0   0

0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

want:

```
26  12  4  3  2  2  0

12  16  2  4  3  2  0

16  14  8  5  2  2  0

17   8  5  3  6  3  0
```

Comment: What have you done to solve your problem? Take a look at [ask].

Comment: You have to be more specific on how you're supposed to obtain what you want. We can't guess. Plus you should definitely try more.